# Why does Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) return True on button release, when targetFrameRate is set?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

Im working on a game in Unity, and for some reason Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) stopped working correctly. The method return true both when I click down, but also when I release the mouse button. Using Input.GetMouseButton**Up**(0) works as it should.

I assured the problem by running this code:

```
void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Debug.Log("Down");
        }
    }
```

And "Down" is logged both on click and release.
Does anyone have a clue why?

Edit:
I just noticed it only happens when a targetFrameRate is set

```
`Application.targetFrameRate = 60;`
```

Removing that line of code removes the problem, but of course I want to be able to control the frame rate.

Comment: You  probably copy/pasted the code changed the GetMouse method to Up but forgot to change the debug message.